# How do I find files that do not end with a newline/linefeed?

Tags: language-agnostic

How can I list normal text (`.txt`) filenames, that don't end with a newline?

e.g.: list (output) this filename:

```
$ cat a.txt
asdfasdlsad4randomcharsf
asdfasdfaasdf43randomcharssdf
$
```

and don't list (output) this filename:

```
$ cat b.txt
asdfasdlsad4randomcharsf
asdfasdfaasdf43randomcharssdf

$
```

Comment: Are you just looking for a wide display of files form a folder down? Your question is not very clear by the example above..

Comment: What does "normal txt" mean? Are you talking about files that ends with a *blank* line (\n\n) or just files that ends with a newline? You could use `od -c filename` to print unambiguous representation of the file.

Comment: Just to emphasize: newline is *not* the same as *blank* line.  A newline is a single character - it delimits what we see as "lines".  A blank line is simply a "line" with no characters, typically 2 consecutive newline characters with nothing in-between, or the first line in a file that begins with a newline.  Some people call lines consisting of only whitespace "blank" lines as well, and reserve the term "empty line" for 2 consecutive newline characters.  You should be clear about what you want.

Comment: Note that in the example you posted, the first file **does** end with a newline, and the second ends with **two** newlines.

Comment: normal text files (according to POSIX) _always_ end with a newline. also consider the two comments above

Answer (score 42):

Use pcregrep, a Perl Compatible Regular Expressions version of grep which supports a multiline mode using -M flag that can be used to match (or not match) if the last line had a newline:

```
pcregrep -LMr '\n\Z' .
```

In the above example we are saying to search recursively (`-r`) in current directory (`.`) listing files that don't match (`-L`) our multiline (`-M`) regex that looks for a newline at the end of a file (`'\n\Z'`)

Changing `-L` to `-l` would list the files that *do* have newlines in them.

`pcregrep` can be installed on MacOS with the homebrew `pcre` package: `brew install pcre`

Comment: I should point out that the answer given by @dennis-williamson also fails for files that has spaces in them.  At least it did for me.

Comment: I added a set of missing quotes in my answer that should take care of that problem.

Comment: Just a note for future readers: this pcregrep command is correct for files that do *not* contain empty lines. Counterexample: `printf "a\n\nb" | pcregrep -M '\n$' -` will print `a` (and thus with running with `-L` will print nothing).

Comment: Use `\Z` instead of `$` (i.e. `pcregrep -LMr '\n\Z' .`) to avoid the issue @maverickwoo mentioned.

Comment: And in case you need to add a newline to them: `pcregrep -LMr '\n\Z' . | xargs sed -i -e '$a\'`

Comment: I don't understand why people always use short options in answers... I get it, it is way faster to type, and maybe also to memorize, but it is also way harder to understand, and people end up copy-pasting commands without even knowing what they are doing

Answer (score 40):

Ok it's my turn, I give it a try:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -L1 bash -c 'test "$(tail -c 1 "$0")" && echo "No new line at end of $0"'
```

Comment: I don't like this dot you added in my answer, you editors. I use GNU find here. Which implementation of find don't yet support in 2020 not giving the path?

Comment: BSD find, which is what is in macOS, requires the path to be specified.

Comment: Sad there's distro lagging behind :,-( In the meantime I bet there's distros that has no `find` at all :,-(

Comment: @JulienPalard The path is not optional in the current (IEEE Std 1003.1-2017) Posix standard so it's not really lagging behind. Giving no path could mean _use the current directory_ or _use my home directory_ or _use the root_ or whatever on different platforms. Giving an error when not given a path is fully compliant.

Comment: worked perfectly for me on macos

Comment: This can also be executed with `find . -type f -exec bash -c 'test "$(tail -c 1 "{}")" && echo "No new line at end of {}"' \;` which avoids using xargs as find's `-exec` generally makes it unnecessary.

Answer (score 19):

If you have [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) installed:

```
rg -Ul '[^\n]\z'
```

That regular expression matches any character which is not a newline, and then [the end of the file](https://docs.rs/regex/1.3.3/regex/#empty-matches). Multi-line mode (`-U`) must be enabled to match on line terminators.

Answer (score 12):

Give this a try:

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c '[ -z "$(sed -n "\$p" "$1")" ]' _ {} \; -print
```

It will print filenames of files that end with a blank line. To print files that don't end in  a blank line change the `-z` to `-n`.

Comment: The answers that use `for ... find ... do` will fail if there are filenames that contain spaces.

Comment: you are correct about `for.. find..` http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29

Comment: Does not work for me. With `-z` it prints nothing, with `-n` it prints all files.

Comment: @AlexeyInkin: If you create a file using this command does the find  (with the `-z` test) output its name? `echo -e 'foo\n' > extranewline` Note that the command is intended to find files that end with a blank line (the last two characters in the file are two newlines).

Comment: @DennisWilliamson yes, it does. But that file has two newlines at the end. The original question was about one newline. I use Ubuntu.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using 'ack' (http://beyondgrep.com) as a alternative to grep, you just run this:

```
ack -v '\n$'
```

It actually searches all lines that don't match (-v) a newline at the end of the line.

Comment: Easy, simple solution. Add '-l' to get just the matched files and not the line.

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in `find $1 -type f -name "*.txt"`;
do
        nlines=`tail -n 1 $file | grep '^$' | wc -l`
        if [ $nlines -eq 1 ]
                then echo $file
        fi
done;
```

Call it this way: `./script dir`

E.g. `./script /home/user/Documents/` -> lists all text files in `/home/user/Documents` ending with `\n`.

Comment: The first improvement is to put `IFS=$'\n'` before for. It allows to handle files with spaces. The second improvement is to replace `$nlines -eq 1` with `$nlines -eq 0` because author needs "filenames, that **doesn't end** with a newline".

Answer (score 3):

The best oneliner I could come up with is this:

```sh
git grep --cached -Il '' | xargs -L1 bash -c 'if test "$(tail -c 1 "$0")"; then echo "No new line at end of $0"; exit 1; fi'
```

This uses `git grep`, because in my use-case I want to ensure files commited to a git branch have ending newlines.

If this is required outside of a git repo, you can of course just use `grep` instead.

```sh
grep -RIl '' . | xargs -L1 bash -c 'if test "$(tail -c 1 "$0")"; then echo "No new line at end of $0"; exit 1; fi'
```

Why I use grep? Because you can easily filter out binary files with `-I`.

Then the usual xargs/tail thingy found in other answers, with the addition to **exit with 1** if a file has no newline. So this can be used in a pre-commit githook or CI.

Comment: Nice work. But git grep version, (tail) gives error if the filename contains space in it.

Answer (score 3):

This example

- Works on macOS (BSD) and GNU/Linux
- Uses standard tools: find, grep, sh, file, tail, od, tr
- Supports paths with spaces

Oneliner:

```sh
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'file -b "{}" | grep -q text' \; -exec sh -c '[ "$(tail -c 1 "{}" | od -An -a | tr -d "[:space:]")" != "nl" ]' \; -print
```

More readable version

- Find under current directory

  - Regular files
  - That 'file' (brief mode) considers text
  - Whose last byte (tail -c 1) is not represented by od's named character "nl"
  - And print their paths

```sh
#!/bin/sh
find . \
    -type f \
    -exec sh -c 'file -b "{}" | grep -q text' \; \
    -exec sh -c '[ "$(tail -c 1 "{}" | od -An -a | tr -d "[:space:]")" != "nl" ]' \; \
    -print
```

Finally, a version with a -f flag to fix the offending files (requires bash).

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# Finds files without final newlines
# Pass "-f" to also fix those files
fix_flag="$([ "$1" == "-f" ] && echo -true || echo -false)"
find . \
    -type f \
    -exec sh -c 'file -b "{}" | grep -q text' \; \
    -exec sh -c '[ "$(tail -c 1 "{}" | od -An -a | tr -d "[:space:]")" != "nl" ]' \; \
    -print \
    $fix_flag \
    -exec sh -c 'echo >> "{}"' \;
```

Answer (score 2):

This is kludgy; someone surely can do better:

```bash
for f in `find . -name '*.txt' -type f`; do
    if test `tail -c 1 "$f" | od -c | head -n 1 | tail -c 3` != \\n; then
        echo $f;
    fi
done
```

N.B. this answers the question in the title, which is different from the question in the body (which is looking for files that end with \n\n I think).

Answer (score 2):

Since your question has the perl tag, I'll post an answer which uses it:

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec perl check.pl {} +
```

where check.pl is the following:

```
#!/bin/perl 

use strict;
use warnings;

foreach (@ARGV) {
    open(FILE, $_);

    seek(FILE, -2, 2);

    my $c;

    read(FILE,$c,1);
    if ( $c ne "\n" ) {
        print "$_\n";
    }
    close(FILE);
}
```

This perl script just open, one per time, the files passed as parameters and read only the next-to-last character; if it is not a newline character, it just prints out the filename, else it does nothing.

Comment: What if the last character is not a newline (of course it's not a valid text file)?

Answer (score 2):

Most solutions on this page do not work for me (FreeBSD 10.3 amd64). Ian Will's 
OSX solution does almost-always work, but is pretty difficult to follow : - (

There is an easy solution that almost-always works too : (if $f is the file) :

sed -i '' -e '$a\' "$f"

There is a major problem with the sed solution : it never gives you the 
opportunity to just check (and not append a newline).

Both the above solutions fail for DOS files. I think the most 
portable/scriptable solution is probably the easiest one, 
which I developed myself : - )

Here is that elementary sh script which combines file/unix2dos/tail. In 
production, you will likely need to use "$f" in quotes and fetch tail output 
(embedded into the shell variable named last) as \"$f\"

```
if file $f | grep 'ASCII text' > /dev/null; then
    if file $f | grep 'CRLF' > /dev/null; then
        type unix2dos > /dev/null || exit 1
        dos2unix $f
        last="`tail -c1 $f`"
        [ -n "$last" ] && echo >> $f
        unix2dos $f
    else
        last="`tail -c1 $f`"
        [ -n "$last" ] && echo >> $f
    fi
fi
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
$ find . -name "*.txt" -print0 | xargs -0I {} bash -c '[ -z "$(tail -n 1 {})" ] && echo {}'
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is the only example in this thread that actually works (on OSX)

Comment: ...actually, this doesn't seem to find the right files

Answer (score 1):

This example works for me on OSX (many of the above solutions did not)

```
for file in `find . -name "*.java"`
do
  result=`od -An -tc -j $(( $(ls -l $file  | awk '{print $5}') - 1 )) $file`
  last_char=`echo $result | sed 's/ *//'`
  if [ "$last_char" != "\n" ]
  then
    #echo "Last char is .$last_char."
    echo $file
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Here another example using little bash build-in commands and which:

- allows you to filter for extension (e.g. `| grep '\.md$'` filters only the `md` files)
- pipe more `grep` commands for extending the filter (like exclusions `| grep -v '\.git'` to exclude the files under `.git`
- use the full power of grep parameters to for more filters or inclusions

The code basically, iterates (`for`) over all the files (matching your chosen criteria `grep`) and if the last 1 character of a file (`-n "$(tail -c -1 "$file")"`) is not not a blank line, it will print the file name (`echo "$file"`).

The verbose code:

```
for file in $(find . | grep '\.md$')
do
    if [ -n "$(tail -c -1 "$file")" ]
    then
        echo "$file"
    fi
done
```

A bit more compact:

```
for file in $(find . | grep '\.md$')
do
    [ -n "$(tail -c -1 "$file")" ] && echo "$file"
done
```

and, of course, the 1-liner for it:

```
for file in $(find . | grep '\.md$'); do [ -n "$(tail -c -1 "$file")" ] && echo "$file"; done
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the most understandable script:

```
for FN in `find . -type f` ; do if [[ `cat "$FN" | tail -c 1 | xxd -p` != '0a' ]] ; then echo "$FN" ; fi ; done
```