# Detect (invalid) text files that do not end in line break

Tags: bash, text

How can I use standard Unix tools to detect files which are "text files" that are invalid because they don't have a final line break?

As we know, an essential property of a text file is that [*every* line is terminated by a line break](https://stackoverflow.com/a/729795/70157). So, I'm trying to find "text files" that fail to conform to that definition, by lacking a final line break.

(For this purpose, an empty file is not a text file because it does not contain text.)

I'm wanting a command that will easily report files encoded as text, but which do not end with a line break.

(**Note:** This is *not* asking about blank lines; it is asking about a "line", that *does not terminate* in a line break, at the end of the file.)

What command (or pipeline) of standard Unix utilities can I use, that will reliably and easily find and report those files?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linux command: How to 'find' only text files?](/q/4767396/4518341)

Comment: Also see [How to find files that don't have empty line at the end? - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/315928/264812).

Comment: How should an empty file be categorized - valid or invalid?

Comment: You can use `tail -c 1` to get the last character of a file.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to those who pointed me to [udondan's answer on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54348931/70157). From that, I have cribbed a solution:

```bash
for f in $(
    grep --binary-files without-match --dereference-recursive --files-with-matches '' .
) ; do
    printf '%s: ' "$f"
    if test "$(tail --bytes 1 "$f")" ; then
        printf "does not end with line break\n"
    else
        printf "ends with line break\n"
    fi
done | grep 'does not end with line break'
```

Comment: Why filter at the end instead of just not outputting from the loop in that case?

Comment: `for f in $()` will fail on filenames containing whitespace.

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) finds a serious problem in the code.  The report that it produces includes a link to more information about the problem and how to fix it.  It's a good idea to run [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on all new and modified shell code.

Comment: You said you wanted a solution using standard Unix tools but `tail --bytes` is not part of the POSIX standard, `tail -c` is. Those `grep` options aren't POSIX either.